# How to Remap the Raspbian “Wheezy” Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I am having a strange problem.

I just finished setting up my wonderful Raspberry Pi, and it works great, except for the fact that it is not compatible with my [wired Mac OSX Keyboard](http://www.apple.com/keyboard/). 
I can type perfectly well - letters and numbers work fine. But, if I attempt to write `"`, the output is `@`. If I write the `@` symbol, `"` comes out. This is extremely annoying - I was hoping to use the Raspberry Pi to test LAN networks in Python, and the `"` symbol is essential.

How can I remap my keyboard to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE**

I found the answer on the [official forums.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=6907) Thank you DancingMan.

**Steps**

1. **Open Terminal as a root user**

   Go to `other>X-Terminal as root (GKsu)`
2. Type in the reconfigure command

   ```
    dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
   ```
3. Follow the prompts

Hopefully that was helpful - this issue had been bugging me for *hours!*

Answer (score 1):

Also in GUI
Menu
 Preferences
  Raspberry Pi Configuration
    Localization tab
     Keyboard (Canada) # in my case!

Then fonts should work correctly

Answer (score -1):

On Raspberry Pi Jesse.

Preferences `->` 
Mouse and Keyboard Settings `->` Keyboard tab `->` Keyboard Layout `->` United States:English(US)

Comment: What has "Jesse"(sic) to do with Wheezy?