# Raspbmc - how to set up keyboard layout *after* first SSH login?

Tags: raspbmc, keyboard

I recently installed Raspbmc (latest version as of April 2013)
I selected a  keyboard layout when I connected with SSH using a laptop.

However, I now want to fix the layout for a physically connected keyboard.

Any idea how I can do that? (Either from the Raspbmc GUI or from the cli)

Comment: There actually happen to be several questions already dealing with this topic. Please see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5601/6609

Comment: I couldn't find that :). Probably because I only tried searching for questions that explicitely mention Raspbmc. At a minimum, my question may help others find this answer easier.

Comment: If starting to reconfigure the keyboard-configuration without mounting the kernel as fs the script will complain about it and will say that the kernelfs is not mounted. Thus the first line is exactly doing this. So I can say Yes! it indeed works.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If so, please mark which one it is by clicking on the green check-mark. We are trying to get this site's Q:A ratio and % answered up to par. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To re-map your keyboard simply go into the terminal and type:

```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then, follow the prompts that appear on the screen.

If you have any issues, please leave a note below in the comments.

**NOTE:** This method works through both the GUI and the CLI interfaces.

Comment: Not sure about the 'GUI' reference in your note. This is Raspbmc - no X there. Is there a way to get a command prompt *inside of* (without quitting) Raspbmc that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @cristi So sorry - I assumed that you were using Raspbian! To the extent of my (albeit limited) knowledge, *There is no way to access terminal in raspmc without quitting.*

Comment: No problem :) I'll try your solution when I get home and mark it as the accepted answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found this works nicely

```
sudo insserv /etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh -d
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo reboot
```

Comment: What does the first line do?

Comment: It enables the `mountkernfs` script or, if you prefer, opens that file and scans the comment at the beginning to try to identify a boot script.
BTW, the `mountkernfs.sh` script does what its name say: mount the kernel onto the fs under the `/sys` and `/proc` directories.

Comment: This is the answer for raspbmc. Raspian has multiple options for configuring things, but due tot eh way raspbmc interfaces, you need to drop to the shell, start mountkernfs, and then run dpkg-configure. Just doing dpkg-configure gives an error that mountkernfs is not running

Comment: So, considering the question was about raspbmc, do you mean this is the correct answer instead of the one with more votes?

Answer (score 0):

This post :

http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=5517

shows that you cannot normally get to the CLI from within Raspbmc, however, this particular post

http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=5517&pid=45120#pid45120

seems to show that it can be done using python.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev <--Installs the Python development?
sudo apt-get install python-pip <--Python package installer
```

then create a file, that contains python script:
Code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start", shell=True)
```

and last, assign this script to a button on remote:

```
RunScript(/home/pi/.xbmc/userdata/pyscript/your_script.py)
```

I suppose that this gets you to the CLI where you can do your keyboard magic

Comment: Great info! But wrong place for it. I asked a separate question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/7262/7203 specifically for you to have a place to move this answer. :)  Would you care to do so? Thx

Comment: have done so, but I thought this was relevant for getting to a command prompt so you can reconfigure the keyboard!