# Raspbmc - can the command-line be accessed from within the GUI?

Tags: raspbmc, gui, terminal

In Raspbmc, I can get to the terminal command-line by hitting the GUI "Power off" button, choosing `Exit` and then hitting `Esc` on the attached keyboard.

My question is: can I get to the command-line without quitting the GUI? (And no, I don't want to SSH to the RasPi box)

Comment: ...I ended up SSH-ing. Less drama :)

Answer (score 1):

This post :

http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=5517

shows that you cannot normally get to the CLI from within Raspbmc, however, this particular post

http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=5517&pid=45120#pid45120

seems to show that it can be done using python.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev <--Installs the Python development?
sudo apt-get install python-pip <--Python package installer
```

then create a file, that contains python script: Code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start", shell=True)
```

and last, assign this script to a button on remote:

```
RunScript(/home/pi/.xbmc/userdata/pyscript/your_script.py)
```

I suppose that this gets you to the CLI where you can do your keyboard magic

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go from GUI to CLI by clicking shutdown and it gave me three options: shutdown, reboot, and exit to command line. that gets you out of GUI